# Bash script in a Perl script hangs

Tags: bash, perl, ffmpeg, macos

I'm running a small bash script in a Perl script on a Mac, but the bash script seems to hang when finished. The Perl script doesn't pick up and continue. The bash script works great in a shell window.

Here is the script

```
for f in *.flac
do
    /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "$f" -aq 1 "${f%flac}mp3"
done
```

and here is how I'm calling it

```
my $mp3Status = system ("/Users/user/bin/flac2mp3_0.sh");
```

Comment: Please, provide more information, e.g. the scripts. As given now, your question is too vague.

Comment: It is a bad practice to mix languages or call another script.  (even it can be a quick win method).  Is  there common environment variables used by both scripts ? Does Perl call the bash script with parameters ?  How Perl script controls the bash script results ?

Comment: Here is how I'm calling the bash script: my $mp3Status = system ("/Users/user/bin/flac2mp3_0.sh");

Comment: No the variables used in the bash script do not appear in the Perl script.

Comment: It depends really on what your shell script does. For all we know it has `sleep 3600` at the end.

Comment: No sleep. The bash script:  for f in *.flac; do
 /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "$f" -aq 1 "${f%flac}mp3"
done

Comment: Please stop providing updates in the comments. I've copied two of your updates back into the question where they can be easily seen, but that should be your responsibility to make it easy for people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you need to specify bash?

```
system("/bin/bash /Users/user/bin/flac2mp3_0.sh");
```

**Edit**: and if still not working try with this syntax (same but with pipe at the end)

```
system("/bin/bash /Users/user/bin/flac2mp3_0.sh|");
```

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion, but it still stopped when done and deleted both the flac and mp3 files! No joy.

Comment: awful and can't see why

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the bash script has the shebang #!/bin/bash at the top and then add exit 0 to the very end of your script so the other program know it exited successfully.

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.flac
do
    /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "$f" -aq 1 "${f%flac}mp3"
done
exit 0
```

Lets try a different way

```
#!/bin/bash
find -name "*.cfg" -type f -exec /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i "$f" -aq 1 "${f%flac}mp3" {} \;
done
exit 0
```

Comment: Good idea, but still not working correctly. I don't understand why other similar scripts worked but this one doesn't. Maybe my bash is wrong? And I do have the shebang.

Comment: I had a similar issue, I had to wrap the entire for loop in a while true  loop and use break in my inner for loop to exit both the loops. I can't remember the details but it is a common issue trying to escape bash for loops correctly. 
Look up bash while and bash until for more details.

Comment: I'm beginning to think it has to do with Perl running another shell when 'system' is used. I've been reading 'Perl Cookbook' and 'Programming Perl' regarding 'system' calls and forks. Getting a bit steep for me.

Comment: just added a bit diferent way of doing the bash script. Your likely right I'm not fond of mixing two script languages.

Comment: I agree. I've had a few issues with quoting (single and double embedded in the same string). But I can't see any other way to do what i want to do. I have a perl script nearly working with a different ffmpeg command but it hangs after about 6 conversions. This one at least converts all files in the directory, but then stops.

Comment: The `exit 0` would just hide the real exit status, and has nothing to do with the script hanging.

Comment: I realize that but was trying to force it to see an exit of 0

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED!! I changed the quoting in the Perl script:

```
@sysCmd=(`/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg` , '-' , "$t" , ' -aq 1', '${t%flac}mp3');
system (@sysCmd);
```

Now I can work on the rest of the Perl script.
Many thanks to all who contributed some ideas.

Comment: I really can't see how this would work. Especially with that last argument in single quotes given that the `t` will be passed on as a literal `t` (what even _is_ `$t`?).  Also, those backticks makes no sense and the `-aq 1` argument should probably be two separate arguments.

Comment: Is this an opinion or from your experience? Because this does work on my box. Have you tried the code? Maybe the quotes can be altered - but that is not my concern right now.

Comment: Backticks in Perl [works in a similar way as in the shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799968), so that part of the first line would actually _run_ `ffmpeg`. Command line processing happens on _words_, but when you use an array with `system()` in Perl, the array elements are the words. This means `-aq 1` would be a single argument, not two as it would be in the shell. In Perl, `'${t%flac}mp3'` is literal, so that is passed to the shell as it is, and the shell has no notion of what `t` is.  I also noticed that `-i` has been shortened to `-`.

Comment: You are right about the '-i' missing - my bad. After reading your comment this morning I ran the script again and it failed. No idea what that is about. I will do more work on this and see what happens.